# does socket buffer occupy process memory address?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

As we know, we can use `setsocketopt` api to alter the socket's buffer size.

Since the socket fd is created by user process, does it occupy process memory address, like the top 1G kernal space in each
process 4G virtual address for 32-bit machine?

And when socket is closed, it seems that the fd is not released until 2MSL time elapsed, which will cause the buffer to exist for longer time.

Comment: Socket buffers are in kernel memory, not process memory. And when a socket is in `TIME-WAIT` state it doesn't need any socket buffers, so I think they're discarded.

Comment: I think [unix.se] would be a better place to ask this, it has no effect on network programming. It's about the internal design of the network stack.